# Solving a differential equation with 2 dependent variables using SciLab

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to solve the following differential equation, which has 2 dependent variables. How do I solve it? And how do I solve it on SciLab?

$kA_{c}\frac{d^2T}{dx^2}+ k\frac{dA_{C}}{dx}\frac{dT}{dx} - hP(T-T_{\infty}) = 0$

In this equation, $A_{c}$ and T are dependent on $x$.

Note: If this is not the right place for the SciLab question, then I apologize in advance...

edit:Oh, and the boundary conditions are:

At $ x = 0; T = T{\infty}$; and at  $x = L; h(T- T{\infty}) = - k \frac{dT}{dx} $

$A_{c}$ will be a user defined function of x.

Comment: What are the boundary conditions? Moreover, you understand that you can't find two functions from a single equation, right?

Comment: This is a heat transfer equation with 2 unknown parameters (A and T). You need to have a supporting equation (It appears you should have an additional equation for area A). You should determine what happens to $A$ respect to $x$. Generally $dA/dx$ tends to be zero in many conditions.

Comment: A is a function of x, which is user defined. And the boundary conditions are now provided in the edited original post.